# Changing a linear map such that given properties are satisfied

Tags: linear-algebra, elementary-number-theory, linear-programming

We are given $\{v_1, \dots, v_s\} \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$, all with the same euclidean norm, say $\|v_i\| = \sqrt{(v_i^{(1)})^2 + \dots + (v_i^{(n)})^2} = 1$. Let's also assume $v_i \notin \text{span}(v_j)$ for all $i \neq j$. Now let $i \in \{1, 2, \dots, s\}$ be fixed.

Is there a $\emptyset \neq J \subseteq \{1, 2, \dots, n\}$ with

$$\sum_{j \in J}|v_i^{(j)}| = \text{max}\{ \sum_{j \in J}|v_{i'}^{(j)}|  ; i' \in \{1, 2, \dots, s\} \} ?$$

---

The edge-cases are clear to me: If $v_i = e_k$ is a standard-basis-Vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$, than we can take $J = \{k\}$. If $v_i = \frac{1}{\|(1, 1, \dots, 1)\|}(1, 1, \dots, 1)$, then we could use $J = \{1, 2, \dots, n\}$. That makes it possible to me that such a $J$ could exist in general.

---

Motivation: I'm given a linear map $u : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ with the property $(u, v_i) > 0$ for all $i \in \{1, 2, \dots, s\}$. Now I want to change $u$ a bit, such that $(u, v_i) = 0$ for at least one $i$ and $(u, v_i) > 0$ for at least one $i$ and $(u, v_i) \geq 0$ for all $i$. So the $i$ I'm fixing above is the one with $(u, v_i) = \text{min}\{(u, v_j) \mid j \in \{1, 2, \dots, s\}\}$ and $J$ ist the index set for values in $u$ I want to change.

Thanks for your ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, technically $J=\emptyset$ would satisfy the required equation. But, if you want $J\neq \emptyset$, unfortunately it is not necessarily possible: if, for example, take $v_1=(2,2,1)/3, v_2=(1,1,1)/\sqrt3,v_3=(1,1,0)/\sqrt2$ and $i=1$, then no $J\neq\emptyset$ will work.

Another counterexample, with integer entries, is $v_1=(11,5,0), v_2=(9,8,1), v_3=(12,1,1)$, with $i=1$.

Comment: Yes, I meant $J \neq \emptyset$ and did change the question in this regard. Thanks for your counter example, then I have to try differently.